# What are the ways to add a html content preview to jQuery Datatables cells

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, datatables

Below is an example to elaborate the situation.
| id       | name           |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | Apple          |
| 2        | Orange         |

I'm using Code Igniter for my project Framework. The datatable is called from serverside and encode into json file return to frontend. Ids are  tags that link to another page. When hovers over the id, I want it to display a preview of what the the page looks like withs few specific data.

In controller.php,
I tried create a variable that stores the html content. But tooltip does not pass html content.

```
$tip_box = 
"<div class='tip_box'>
<div class='tip_content'>
  <h2>".$row->name."</h2>
  <div>".$row->description."</div>
</div>
</div>";

$id = '<a href="'.site_url('controller/info').'" data-tooltip="'.$tip_box.'">$row->id</a>';
```

Comment: Sorry if the table is not working, in my preview the table is working fine. Somehow when post the comment the table is not working.